# Android protobuf nano documentation

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers

I am trying to reduce the number of methods that are generated by Google proto-buf and one of the alternatives is to use proto-buf nano. However I found no documentation on how to use it. Except the [package link](https://github.com/android/platform_external_protobuf/tree/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/nano), I can't find anything on how to generate java files from proto files using nano.

So the question is straight-forward: how to use google proto nano in order to generate java classes from proto files and how to use them in a project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the main protobuf compiler source code:

```
#include <google/protobuf/compiler/javanano/javanano_generator.h>
.... 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    google::protobuf::compiler::CommandLineInterface cli;
    cli.AllowPlugins("protoc-");
    ...
    // Proto2 JavaNano
    google::protobuf::compiler::javanano::JavaNanoGenerator javanano_generator;
    cli.RegisterGenerator("--javanano_out", &javanano_generator,
    "Generate Java source file nano runtime.");

    return cli.Run(argc, argv);
}
```

looking at [protobuf's Readme](https://github.com/android/platform_external_protobuf/blob/master/java/README.txt)

> **Nano Generator options**
>
> - `java_package           -> <file-name>|<package-name>`
> - `java_outer_classname   -> <file-name>|<package-name>`
> - `java_multiple_files    -> true or false`
> - `java_nano_generate_has -> true or false [DEPRECATED]`
> - `optional_field_style   -> default or accessors`
> - `enum_style             -> c or java`

**To use nano protobufs outside of Android repo:**

> - Link with the generated jar file   `<protobuf-root>java/target/protobuf-java-2.3.0-nano.jar.`
> - Invoke with `--javanano_out`, e.g.:
>
> `./protoc '--javanano_out=java_package=src/proto/simple-data.proto|my_package,java_outer_classname=src/proto/simple-data.proto|OuterName:.' src/proto/simple-data.proto`

**To use nano protobufs within the Android repo:**

> - Set '`LOCAL_PROTOC_OPTIMIZE_TYPE := nano`' in your local .mk file.   When building a Java library or an app (package) target, the build
>     system will add the Java nano runtime library to the
>     `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` variable, so you don't need to.
> - Set '`LOCAL_PROTO_JAVA_OUTPUT_PARAMS := ...`' in your local .mk file   for any command-line options you need. Use commas to join multiple
>     options. In the nano flavor only, whitespace surrounding the option
>     names and values are ignored, so you can use backslash-newline or
>     '+=' to structure your make files nicely.
> - The options will be applied to *all* proto files in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`   when you build a Java library or package. In case different options
>     are needed for different proto files, build separate Java libraries
>     and reference them in your main target. Note: you should make sure
>     that, for each separate target, all proto files imported from any
>     proto file in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` are included in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`. This
>     is because the generator has to assume that the imported files are
>     built using the same options, and will generate code that reference
>     the fields and enums from the imported files using the same code
>     style.
> - Hint: '`include $(CLEAR_VARS)`' resets all `LOCAL_` variables, including the two above.

Simple nano example from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/protobuf/+/master/src/google/protobuf/.

**unittest_simple_nano.proto**

```
package protobuf_unittest_import;

option java_package = "com.google.protobuf.nano";
// Explicit outer classname to suppress legacy info.
option java_outer_classname = "UnittestSimpleNano";

message SimpleMessageNano {
  message NestedMessage {
    optional int32 bb = 1;
  }

  enum NestedEnum {
    FOO = 1;
    BAR = 2;
    BAZ = 3;
  }

  optional int32 d = 1 [default = 123];
  optional NestedMessage nested_msg = 2;
  optional NestedEnum default_nested_enum = 3 [default = BAZ];
}
```

**Command line**

```
./protoc '--javanano_out=java_package=google/protobuf/unittest_simple_nano.proto|com.google.protobuf.nano,java_outer_classname=google/protobuf/unittest_simple_nano.proto|UnittestSimpleNano:target/generated-test-sources' google/protobuf/unittest_simple_nano.proto
```

**Test extracted from [NanoTest.java](https://github.com/android/platform_external_protobuf/blob/master/java/src/test/java/com/google/protobuf/NanoTest.java)**

```
  public void testSimpleMessageNano() throws Exception {
    SimpleMessageNano msg = new SimpleMessageNano();
    assertEquals(123, msg.d);
    assertEquals(null, msg.nestedMsg);
    assertEquals(SimpleMessageNano.BAZ, msg.defaultNestedEnum);

    msg.d = 456;
    assertEquals(456, msg.d);

    SimpleMessageNano.NestedMessage nestedMsg = new SimpleMessageNano.NestedMessage();
    nestedMsg.bb = 2;
    assertEquals(2, nestedMsg.bb);
    msg.nestedMsg = nestedMsg;
    assertEquals(2, msg.nestedMsg.bb);

    msg.defaultNestedEnum = SimpleMessageNano.BAR;
    assertEquals(SimpleMessageNano.BAR, msg.defaultNestedEnum);

    byte [] result = MessageNano.toByteArray(msg);
    int msgSerializedSize = msg.getSerializedSize();
    //System.out.printf("mss=%d result.length=%d\n", msgSerializedSize, result.length);
    assertTrue(msgSerializedSize == 9);
    assertEquals(result.length, msgSerializedSize);

    SimpleMessageNano newMsg = SimpleMessageNano.parseFrom(result);
    assertEquals(456, newMsg.d);
    assertEquals(2, msg.nestedMsg.bb);
    assertEquals(SimpleMessageNano.BAR, msg.defaultNestedEnum);
  }
```

There are a lot of test cases in the same class, and looking at the project [pom](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/protobuf/+/35d9fd84ff1d9ecdb91156b757cc9fdcc3f25249/java/pom.xml) you can find a `maven-antrun-plugin` configuration to generate that test resource classes

```
<!-- java nano -->
<exec executable="../src/protoc">
  <arg value="--javanano_out=java_package=google/protobuf/unittest_import_nano.proto|com.google.protobuf.nano,java_outer_classname=google/protobuf/unittest_import_nano.proto|UnittestImportNano:target/generated-test-sources" />
  <arg value="--proto_path=../src" />
  <arg value="--proto_path=src/test/java" />
  <arg value="../src/google/protobuf/unittest_nano.proto" />
  <arg value="../src/google/protobuf/unittest_simple_nano.proto" />
  <arg value="../src/google/protobuf/unittest_stringutf8_nano.proto" />
  <arg value="../src/google/protobuf/unittest_recursive_nano.proto" />
  <arg value="../src/google/protobuf/unittest_import_nano.proto" />
  <arg value="../src/google/protobuf/unittest_enum_multiplejava_nano.proto" />
  <arg value="../src/google/protobuf/unittest_multiple_nano.proto" />
</exec>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering ... will give it a try later and get back

Comment: I tried to go the way you suggested and I am stuck. Can you please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22712937/1051783)?