# Android protobuf nano usage

Tags: java, android, maven, protocol-buffers

I am trying to generate java files from below proto file using protobuf nano. I got some basic instruction on how to proceed in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22247951/1051783).

I have this proto file, `personal.proto`:

```
package tutorial;

option java_package = "com.example.tutorial";
option java_outer_classname = "AddressBookProtos";

message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;
}

message AddressBook {
  repeated Person person = 1;
}
```

I tried to follow the instruction [from here](https://github.com/android/platform_external_protobuf/blob/master/java/README.txt), more specifically *NANO version*:

1. Downloaded `protobuf-2.5.0.zip` and compiler `protoc-2.5.0-win32.zip` from [here](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list).
2. Unzipped `protobuf-2.5.0.zip` to a folder and in there in `src` subfolder I unzipped `protoc.exe`.
3. Changed to `java` folder and in there issued: `mvn clean package -P nano`. That command ran fine and in `target` folder I have `protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar`

From here I am not sure how to proceed since in the [initial documentation](https://github.com/android/platform_external_protobuf/blob/master/java/README.txt) I have this statement:

```
- Link with the generated jar file
  <protobuf-root>java/target/protobuf-java-2.3.0-nano.jar.
```

I am not sure what that means, how to link? Is there some parameter for `protoc.exe` that specifies the jar file to use?

I tried to issue this command: `protoc --javanano_out=enum_style=java --java_out=generated personal.proto`

but I get this error: `--javanano_out: protoc-gen-javanano: The system cannot find the file specified`.

The question would be: what am I missing/doing wrong above? I am trying to generate java files from above proto file.

Comment: I think this protoc is not compiled with javanano support.

Comment: Please excuse my noob question, but how does one compile protoc with `javanano support`?

Comment: I haven't compiled protoc ... I just took it from proto code.google

Comment: Yep, I know but the pre-compiled windows version 2.5.0 does not include nano support, take a look at the source code, in the "src\google\protobuf\compiler" path, includes the java generator but not the javanano generator. The latest source code at google repositories includes javanano https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/protobuf/+/master/src

Comment: Should I use an older version? ... or should I get the latest source code and compile it?

Comment: Tried an older version and I have the same problem. Do you know what should I configure in order to build protobuf with nano enabled?

Comment: Following [thid project](https://github.com/android/platform_external_protobuf)

Comment: You always can compile the source code using MinGW with msys, take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243816/how-to-build-google-protocol-buffers-in-windows-for-mingw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this `protoc` is not compiled with `javanano` support.

The pre-compiled windows version 2.5.0 does not include nano support, take a look at the source code, in the "`src\google\protobuf\compiler`" path, includes the java generator but not the javanano generator. The latest [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/protobuf/+/master/src) at google repositories includes javanano.

You can download the [latest source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/protobuf/+archive/master.tar.gz) and try to compile it using MinGW and msys or [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/), take a look at this post [How to build google protocol buffers in Windows for mingw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243816/how-to-build-google-protocol-buffers-in-windows-for-mingw)

(I will post details for the building process later)

**UPDATE:**

The final command line after building `protoc.exe`

**For one proto file**

```
protoc --javanano_out=store_unknown_fields=true:target/generated-sources personal.proto, target/generated-sources
```

**For multiple proto files**

```
protoc --javanano_out=store_unknown_fields=true:target/generated-sources --proto_path=inputpath input/*.proto
```

**EDIT** Nano generator replaces enum members with `public static final int` fields. This is a problem if a class has an optional enum member because that member will be compiled to a primitive `int` value and will take the default value of zero, which will be the first element from enum. To distinguish the cases when an enum value was not set, one can take advantage of `optional_field_style` parameter that will generate `java.lang.Integer` instead of a primitive int. When the proto is parsed, the caller can check if the value is null before using the value. Null means the value was not set.

The above call script can become:

```
protoc --javanano_out=store_unknown_fields=true,optional_field_style=reftypes:target/generated-sources --proto_path=input input/*.proto
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to keep the enums? Protobuf nano is not generating enums, but instead it makes them static final ints. This is a big problem if suppose I have some class variable as enum and that can be null, but if that is made a primive it gets a default value.

Comment: Is not possible, as micro, nano keep the enums as static int constants. Hehehe, I am very very near to Romania :)

Comment: There is a possibility, you can modify the "src\google\protobuf\compiler\javanano\javanano_enum*" source classes with same classes located in "src\google\protobuf\compiler\java\java_enum*" and recompile an build your own version with enum support.

Comment: Tried it by copying `java_enum` content to `javanano_enum`, changing the namespace but it gives me then some compile errors that I really don't know how to fix since my knowledge of C++ is very poor.

Comment: Found a better alternative: `optional_field_style=reftypes`. This will use java.lang.Integer instead of primitive int. If you don't mind, I will update your answer with this information for future readers.

Comment: Instead of getting a protoc executable that has javanano how would you tell Android Studio to not use javanano and just the regular java?

Comment: I don't understand your question really, do you want to use protocol buffers (micro, without nano support) with Android Studio?