# How to create java pojo from the existing protobuf file?

Tags: java, pojo, protocol-buffers

I am trying to convert .proto (version 2.5) to java pojo. For example

From

```
message Article {
    optional string title = 1;
}
```

to

```
public class Article {
    private string title;

    public string getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(string title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

But the official protoc doesn't support generate pojo way java files.

Is there any tools that automatically generate pojo from .proto files?

Comment: And what happened when you tried?

Comment: Too many .proto files, I need a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SO thread contains documentation for generating the Java "nano" variant of protocol buffers, which might just be what you are looking for: [Android protobuf nano documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247951/android-protobuf-nano-documentation)

Otherwise, the simplest way to generate code on your own is probably to use the google open source protocol buffer code generator to generate "[descriptors](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.FileDescriptor)" for your protocol buffers, and then iterate the descriptors (and perhaps use a library such as java poet) to generate Java code.

Comment: Java "nano" variant of generated files are not the pojo style, too. But  parsing the descriptors may be the only way to do it.

Comment: For your example, the generated nano code should nearly match... What difference makes it not suitable for your case?

Comment: In my case, There are some proto files to describe the data structure, but  I don't want to compile java rely on protobuf, because the real data format is json. But thanks dude, I wrote a rough script to generate pojo by descriptor, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at: https://github.com/sagroskin/protoc-gen-pojo

This is using the "descriptors" of the proto file

- I does not keep comments or documentation.
- No getter or setters.
- One output .java file per .proto file

However with a little work it could solve your use case.

example.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Article {
    string title = 1;
}

enum yesno {
  no = 0;
  yes = 1;
}
```

```
git clone https://github.com/sagroskin/protoc-gen-pojo.git
cd protoc-gen-pojo
go build
# Run protobuf/bin/protoc with this plugin
protoc --plugin=./protoc-gen-pojo --proto_path=./ --pojo_out=./ example.proto
```

And it will create example.java

```
// Code generated by protoc-gen-pojo.

public enum yesno {
    no (0),
    yes (1),
}

public class Article {
    public String title;
}
```